# How to un-highline WPF DataGrid row?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid and I need to select some rows in the DataGrid. After done selecting, the blue highline remains on the row, and I can't figure out how to get rid of it. I tried clicking somewhere else but the blue-highline remains on the row.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to remove the blue highlight border permanently??

Comment: @RV1987 I just don't want it to be highlined. E.g. the third row is highlined but I want it to be un-highlined just like the other row. Where should I click to remove the highline?

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the event IsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged in your code behind file to set the SelectedItem to null like this -

```
private void dg_IsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
   if (!(bool)e.NewValue)
   {
       (sender as DataGrid).SelectedItem = null;
   }
}
```

Xaml file:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg" IsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged="dg_IsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged"/>
```

In case you dont want the selection border in your datagrid, you need to override System.HighlightBrush and add it to your datagrid Resources like this -

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
       <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
       <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black"/>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
<DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I do not know what exactly you want to do, you can control the the highline with redefining DataGridCell and DataGridRow styles. I'll show you an example, which may or may not be the thing you want to do. I wish it helps with you.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                        Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                        Value="0" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsFocused"
                        Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background"
                        Value="Transparent" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground"
                        Value="Black" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <DockPanel>
        <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top"></TextBox>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```